# PHP remove img tag with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i can get text from tags between `</a></div>` and `<div class="toolz">`. in result of that i have `img` tag with `<br />` after that.

for example:

```
<img alt="TEXT" title="TEXT"src="IMAGE LINK" /><br />
```

how to remove from that with preg_replace?

```
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<?php
    $handle='http://www.namefa.ir/Names.asp?pn=4&sx=M&fc=%D8%A2';
    preg_match_all('/<\/a><\/div>(.*?)\s*<div[^>]+class="toolz"[^>]*>\s*/si', file_get_contents($handle), $matching_data);
    $default = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>(.*)\/><br />/is', "", $matching_data);
    echo'<pre>';print_r($default);echo'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Why are you printing `default` instead of `$default` ?

Comment: do you want to extract image urls from <IMG> tags?

Comment: @Robin. this paste is wrong

Comment: `$matching_data` is an array, not a string..

Comment: @asim-ishaq. no i want to remove that with `<br />`

Comment: @Philipp. ok. pattern is true?

Comment: IF the data is mutiline you can use /g at the end of regular expression currently /sig

Comment: @TuxWorld the patterns might be correct, but the code logic is a litte bit confusing..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you code has some logical mistakes.. you have to use an loop to iterate through your search results and replace the tags in your original content. What you do now, seems a little bit useless.

```
$handle='http://www.namefa.ir/Names.asp?pn=4&sx=M&fc=%D8%A2';
$content = file_get_contents($handle);
preg_match_all('/<\/a><\/div>(.*?)\s*<div[^>]+class="toolz"[^>]*>\s*/si', $content, $matching_data, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matching_data as $match) {
    $replace = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*>(.*)\/><br />/is', "", $match[0]);
    $content = str_replace($matching_data[0], $replace, $content);
}
echo'<pre>';print_r($content);echo'</pre>';
```

It seems your inner regex to replace the image is wrong.. at least it doesn't find something - are you sure, the `<br />` is correct, or if you just want to find a simple line break

Comment: I guess you mean `$match` instead of `$matching_data[0]` in the foreach loop.